# What is relative distance and how can you tell?

Tags: vectors, education

In velocity vectors (Apparent path), the time taken for 2 objects to intercept is:

$$\frac{\text{Relative distance}}{\text{Relative velocity}}$$

What does **Relative distance** mean, and how do can you tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, relative distance just means distance. If the two objects are described as $x(t),y(t)$, the distance is
$$ rd(t) = \|x(t)-y(t)\|_2 $$
were $\|.\|_2$ is the euclidian norm on $\mathbb{R^3}$. It is more or less defined by the pythagorean theorem.

$$\left\|\left(\begin{array}{lll}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{array}\right)\right\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$$

Denote $\dot{x}$ as the derivative of $x$ with respect to the time $t$, then the relative velocity can described as
$$rv(t) = \|\dot{x}(t)-\dot{y}(t)\|_2.$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are vectors it is necessary to take the norm of both expressions. Otherwise, the division in your formula makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the definition above, can you explain in a simpler way that relates to:

∥ x**j** + y**j** ∥

And:

V_P = V_(P/Q) + V_Q

Comment: $x'$ and $\dot{x}$ denote the the same thing here. In pysics, it is very common to describe derivatives with respect to time with dots (like $\dot{x}$) and derivatives with respect to space (i.e. slopes) with primes (like $x'$)

Comment: So does that mean the notation means x**i** ? 

I have another question, without using the derivative definition, can you explain about relative distance please? 

I'm so sorry, but I haven't learned such complex Physics.

Comment: I used the derivative only to describe relative velocities. I would recommend you to read into euclidian norms. That should cover the "what is a distance" question. I honestly don't know what you mean by $x{\bf i}$

Comment: It's okay, I will do as you said, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When 2 objects collide, the initial relative displacement vector is parallel to the relative velocity.

To calculate the time taken, you need the initial distance between them (magnitude of initial relative displacement) divided by the relative speed (magnitude of relative velocity).